# Ошибка python при вызове через cron

Tags: python, linux, sqlite, cron

У меня бот-напоминалка, раз в день отсылает сообщения. Текст и отправителя получает из БД. Бот написан на **python3** БД - **SQLite3**. При вызове скрипта из консоли командой

```
python3 sendpar4.py
```

Скрипт успешно работает без ошибок, однако при зпуске через CRON

```
30 14 * * * /usr/bin/python3.7 /home/pi/Documents/********/sendpar4.py
```

Список заданий Cron
[image: Cron]

Вызов БД в скрипте

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("Me.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

Возникает ошибка(других ошибок в syslog файле нет)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Documents/***********/sendpar4.py", line 15, in <module>
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM usersgroup WHERE 1")
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: usersgroup
```

Проверял также саму БД, записи есть(на это же и указывает безошибочная работа при ручном запуске). В интернетах нашел, что нужно сделать файл исполняемым `chmod +x` Не помогло. Как решить данную проблему?

Comment: отдельное задание в cron создано или там список?

Comment: 1) Путь к базе указан относительный или абсолютный? 2) Какая активная директория будет у скрипта при запуске того через крон?

Comment: @PotroNik Добавил в вопрос скрин из crontab

Comment: @gil9red Про активную директорию в первый раз слышу, как определить? Добавил В вопрос  скрин заданий и код вызова(БД скорее всего локальный путь имеет)

Comment: `30 14 * * * cd /home/pi/Documents/********/ && /usr/bin/python3.7 sendpar4.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы файл исполнялся из своей родной директории в него необходимо сначала перейти, а уже потом запустить скрипт

```
30 14 * * * cd /home/pi/Documents/********/ && /usr/bin/python3.7 sendpar4.py
```

Comment: Лучше научить скрипт воспринимать конфигурацию (либо через командную строку, либо из файла, либо оба варианта).